# How to get only part of a WMS GetCapabilities request

Tags: geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

Is it possible to modify the WMS GetCabilites request URL in order to get back a certain part?

For instance I am only interested in this part of the XML:

```
<LatLonBoundingBox minx="16.6176088621753" miny="44.782391955068526" maxx="53.325886544307956" maxy="62.785875486994094"/>
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:32632" minx="1000000.0" miny="6000000.0" maxx="4000000.0" maxy="7000000.0"/>
```

Comment: You'd need to provide details of your development environment if you want assistance in parsing out what you want from the stsndard-defined response.

Comment: I am not interested in parsing the XML. I want to know, if it is possible to modify the URL request, so that I only get the part I am interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this, the whole point of the GetCapabilties request is to tell you everything about the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that one can restrict the response to just one layer, in case the OP was facing this issue with hundreds of layers resulting in thousands of lines returned.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).